# Importing specific text from text file into excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to import a text file into Excel through VBA, but after a lot of searching and tests I can't seem to figure out how to format it as I want.

Here's a part of the text file:

```
^USER ADDRESS
User's name
Street address
Postal code and town
^USER ORDER NUMBER
Order number
^AND SO ON.....
```

When importing, I want it to format it like this:

```
^USER ADDRESS | User's name | Street address | Postal code and town
^USER ORDER NUMBER | Order number
^AND SO ON ....
```

This is my script this far. It copies the rows including ^USER and pastes it - but I need it to copy the row(s) below each ^ until the next ^.

```
Private Sub DatafrmTxt()

Dim myFile As String, text As String
Dim F As Long
Dim x As Integer

myFile = "C:\test.txt"

F = FreeFile
x = 1

Open myFile For Input As F
Do Until EOF(F)
Line Input #F, text

If InStr(text, "^USER ") > 0 Then
Range("A" & x).Value = text
x = x + 1
End If
Loop
Close F

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job. When the next line in your .txt file isn't a 'header', then paste in the adjacent column to `x`

```
Private Sub DatafrmTxt()

Dim myFile As String, text As String
Dim F As Long
Dim x As Integer, col As Integer

myFile = "C:\test.txt"

F = FreeFile
x = 1

Open myFile For Input As F
Do Until EOF(F)
Line Input #F, text

   If InStr(text, "^USER ") > 0 Then
      Range("A" & x).Value = text
      x = x + 1
      col = 2
   Else
      Cells(x, col).Value = text
      col = col + 1
   End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help, I've not got the correct file, so tried it with HTML using HTML tags, it may need some tweaking.  It uses the Scripting Runtime reference

```
Sub TestTextStream()

Dim f As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim t As Scripting.TextStream
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim intXshift As Integer

Set f = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

 Set t = f.OpenTextFile("c:\test\JavascriptAccordian.txt", ForReading)

lngRow = 1

While Not t.AtEndOfStream

    If Left(t.ReadLine, 1) = "^" Then
        intXshift = 0
        lngRow = lngRow + 1
        Range("a" & lngRow).value = t.ReadLine
    Else
        Range("b" & lngRow).Offset(0, intXshift).value = t.ReadLine
        intXshift = intXshift + 1
    End If

Wend

Set t = Nothing
Set f = Nothing

End Sub
```